# how to use arduino uno millis function()

Tags: arduino

I  wrote  a program for Arduino UNO with attached Funshield, which will animate the following pattern on the four vertical LEDs.At any given moment, exactly one LED (of four) is turned on (we are starting with the topmost one). In each step of the animation, the active LED moves one slot down. When it hits the bottom, it bounces and moves upwards again, until it reaches top. The animation repeats itself forever.
One step of the animation takes exactly 300ms

```
#include <funshield.h>


int ledPin[] = {led1_pin, led2_pin, led3_pin, led4_pin};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 5-1; i>=0; i--)
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
    
  for (i; i<5; i++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
  }
}
```

if i  using the delay() function, it works perfectly，but when i  used millis() function  , 4 LEDs light up at the same time.I would like to know what is causing the animation to stall.

```
#include "funshield.h"

unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned long currentMillis;
const unsigned long period = 300;
const byte liu = 4;
int ledPin[] = { led1_pin, led2_pin, led3_pin, led4_pin };

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
    startMillis = millis();
}

void loop()
{
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period)
        int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > 4; i++) {
        digitalWrite(liu, !digitalRead(liu));
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
        startMillis = currentMillis;
    }

    
    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        digitalWrite(liu, !digitalRead(liu));
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
        startMillis = currentMillis;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very wrong to me: `if(unsigned long)(millis()-nowtime>300)` The parenthesis don't group what we want to group. Fixing that might fix the compile problem.  To use `millis()` you'll have to update `nowtime` and store it outside of the `loop` (otherwise it gets re-established - so make it `static`). Also, the first `for` loop in the second example is missing a `{`. Same with both `for` loops in the first example. Turn on "verbose logging" to see all the error messages.

Comment: An array with 4 elements can be accessed with an index in the range 0 .. 3 only, btw.

Comment: Your `if` statement does nothing. It just declares a variable and assigns it to 0 in it's own scope. The `for` loops then use their own `i` variable. Replacing `delay` with `millis` isn't that trivial. You need to make a [Finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Answer (score 0):

first of all `unsigned long nowTime;` should be at the top, outside of your loop

secondly, you need to use `nowTime = millis();` for the specific time that you want to record the current time (this should be before you use the (millis()-nowtime>300)

and lastly, remove (unsigned long)
from this line
`if(unsigned long)(millis()-nowtime>300)`

for further clarification on how to use millis, read [this article](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) on arduino's official website

Comment: OP changed the question with syntactically correct code. Either edit your answer to answer their current question or just delete it. And typo questions shouldn't be answered in the first place, since aren't considered on-topic here.